# Use mocha programmatically via rest

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, appium

currently I try to figure out, how I can run mocha tests on a GET request of `localhost:3000/run/tests` resource.

Most things seems to work fine, but mocha `.on('end')` is probably not fired correctly so my `res.json(...)` function is not called and node still hangs.

```js
var Mocha = require('mocha');
...    

app.get('/run/tests', (req, res) => {
    var mocha = new Mocha({
        reporter: 'json'
    });

    myTestFiles.forEach(testfile => mocha.addFile('./tests/' + testfile + '.js'));

    mocha.run()
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log(this.testResults);
        res.json(this.testResults);
    });
});
```

I get expected output except the "0 passing" lines :

```
> ...
> CALL element.text()
> GET /session/:sessionID/element/9/text
> RESPONSE element.text() "Username"
  √ App login finished: 37685ms

  0 passing (0ms)
  0 passing (16ms)
```

My testfile looks like this:

```
'use strict';
require('./helpers/setup');

var wd = require('wd');
var serverConfigs = require('./helpers/appium-servers');

describe('Carnet App', function () {
    this.timeout(120000);
    var driver;
    var allPassed = true;

    before(function () {
        var serverConfig = serverConfigs.local;
        driver = wd.promiseChainRemote(serverConfig);
        require('./helpers/logging').configure(driver);
        var desired = {
           'appium-version': '1.4.16',
           platformVersion: '6.0.1',
           device: 'Android',
           platformName: 'Android',
           app: myapp.apk'
        };
        return driver
        .init(desired)
        .setImplicitWaitTimeout(120000);
    });

    after(function (done) {
    return driver
        .quit()
        .done();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        allPassed = allPassed && this.currentTest.state === 'passed';
    });

    it('App login finished', function () {
        return driver
        .elementById('...')
        .click()
        .sendKeys('...')
        .elementById('...')
        .text().should.become('Username');
    });
});
```

Do I make a mistake? Does anybody have expirence with wd + mocha programmatically? Thanks for help!

Comment: Looks like its an async issue...so your job is finishing before a test execution. in your `it()` function towards the bottom...pass `done` into your call back and below the `should.become` call `done()`.

Comment: You mean ```it('App login finished', function (```*done*```) {``` and ```.done();```  after ```.text().should.become('Username')``` ? Seems that this also never finished the mocha process... But if I change ```mocha.run().on('end'``` .... to ```mocha.run(function (failures) { res.json({}) }``` this seems to work and call ```res.json``` after mocha finished the tests. But I can not react on single 'test end' events.

Comment: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically seems you may be using the event handlers differently as they are called within the cb that is passed to `.run()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem by only modify the following:

```
mocha.run(function(failures){
    res.json({ ... })
})
.on('test', function() {
    // do some logging stuff (into a var retured by res.json above)
})

// ... all mocha events possible
// see https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/runner.js#L49

.on('test end', function() {
    // do some advanced logging stuff
});
```